# SAML 2.0 implementation in ASP.Net MVC 4 as IDP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0

I know there have been lot of posts on SAML implementation in .net and believe me I have gone through all of them. I also looked at the Code Project article "Performing a SAMP Post with C#, but the code is very complex, I did not understand why the XSD's are required and was there any library being used. Anyway, I understand the workflow and my requirement is that I have a asp.net mvc project which needs to post data to a saml service provider. So my app is the Identity provider and users login to my app and then after proper validation of health information are redirected to service provider where SAML communication is required. To do this i installed the Ultimate SAML 2.0 trial package from nuget but I am not really sure how to use it. how to post data to it from my mvc page. I am not clear where to start ? Kindly help.

I saw the Sustainsys/Saml2 link but thats for making the asp.net mvc application as a service provider. But mine is to make it a Identity Provider.

Yesterday when I posted this question I was not clear too on what exactly I needed help, but after some digging last night, I think I understood.
As explained above, my web application is the IDP, so I do not need to develop any IDP, all I need to do be able to do is send a SAML response containing a SAML assertion to the Service Provider using HttpPost C# and if there is any free library to do this, I know the Ultimate SAML API in Nuget but its not free.

Comment: Can you edit your question and make it more clear? I don't know if you are looking for a library to implement a SAML2.0 IdP or you don't know how to add the token in the header to do something on and EndPoint supporting SAML2.0 authentication, if you clarify your question I can provide an answer...

Comment: Have a look at: https://itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2 The open source ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 package adds SAML-P support for both Identity Provider (IdP) and Relying Party (RP) on top of the SAML 2.0 functionality implemented in .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of [SAML stacks](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) out there but they are predominantly client side.

The only one that fits your bill (server side and .NET) is ComponentSpace.

Writing a SAML stack is hard and there's a lot of cryptography involved.

Having an application as an IDP is unusual.

Maybe use identityserver4 pointing to your DB as the IDP? It's open source but you would have to purchase the Rock Solid Knowledge SAML stack. Also it's .NET Core.

Or don't use SAML - use OpenID Connect. It's REST API and much simpler to develop.

Comment: Thanks for the info.The Service Providers requires us to send a  signed SAML response with assertions, so I have to use SAML. I did look at the componentSpace, its rather easy to use but again as I said its not free.

Comment: I looked at the oneLogin stack, but I think its only for Service Provider initiated SAML not for IDP initiated SAML, I see the examples are mostly for receiving the SAML assertions not for sending the SAML Responses, do you know anything which  can be used for that ?

Comment: No - I don't know of a free one.

Comment: Just curious, why is having an application as an IDP unusual? Isn't that what an IDP is - just an application that handles identifying a user?

Comment: In the terminology, the relying party or service provider is normally called the application. This connects to an IDP. So if you had a MVC application you wouldn't connect that to the RP / SP. You'd connect directly to the IDP. But yes, the IDP is itself an application in the broader sense..

Comment: Agree with @IsaacVidrine - the IDP in the app is usual scenario. Also I'm wondered why there is no nuget packages providine SAML IDP functionality.